Possible to get youtube monetisation data for YouTube videos via API
I'd like to find out the monetisation status for YouTube videos for which I have access to via OAuth credentials. This data is visible/available in YouTube Studio - is this accessed via a private API that isn't available to general API consumers?
Thanks,
Alistair

If is not described in the documentation, then, it's not possible via YouTube API.
This is the only info I found about the monetization - but, it is for livebroacasts.
